# Bouncy Castle JCE provider alternatives

Tags: bouncycastle

Right now we are trying to evaluate various open source JCE providers for encryption and signing capabilities for our project. It is J2EE based web application project.
I came across "Legion of the Bouncy Castle" which seems to satisfy our requirements. Though before finalizing to it, I want to know its pros and cons and its evaluation w.r.t. nearest competitor?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question some time ago and failed. I couldn't find any OS alternative to Bouncy Castle, so we ended up using it - for verifying the signature of GPG-signed archives. It works quite well, although there is no real documentation and searching for examples on the net is not trivial. So expect a little experimentation - I'd say 1-2 days to get yourself familiarized with it.

Comment: 1) What are the features did u use of it? 2)Was performance of algorithms important consideration for your project? I want to evaluate its performance too.

Comment: I am also in the middle of experimenting with Bouncycastle and I can confirm that it is not easy for a newbie to understand how things work, as up-to-date documentation and especially examples are hard to find. In my case I try to parse an X.509 certificate (all the attributes out of it) and I have so far not found a practical example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of other *open source* JCE providers (unless you count [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/)). But in general, I've found BouncyCastle to be a superb provider with tons of capabilities, and portability good enough to never fail me so far.

Performance was fine for our needs, YMMV (but probably not that much).